# Create a Hyperlink that links to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a hyperlink in a sheet called "Summary-Champion Specific" that links to a sheet called "Hidden Sheet". I've tried using the following code where P1 and P and iterative numbers however cannot get it to work.

```
 Sheets("c").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("c").Range(Cells(P1, P), Cells(P1, P)), Address:="", SubAddress:=Sheets("Hidden Sheet").Range(Cells(P1, P), Cells(P1, P)).Address(External:=True)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is "Hidden Sheet" hidden? If yes, your hyperlink doesn't take you anywhere.

Comment: It's currently not, I'm hoping to unhide the sheet then hide it again within the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sheets("Summary-Champion Specific").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Summary-Champion Specific").Cells(p1, p), Address:="", SubAddress:=Sheets("Hidden Sheet").Cells(p1, p).Address(External:=True)
```

in any case, should "Hidden Sheet" worksheet be hidden, the link wouldn't bring you anywhere